# why are the characters within my string printing in the wrong order only on the windows command prompt?

Tags: java, string, windows, output, command-prompt

i have created a small piece of code that simply scrambles a string using the random number generator. Everything works fine when i run the program using netbeans. However, if i try to run the .jar file from the command prompt the output is garbled. It doesnt seem to be garbled randomly though, the last few letters always show up first. Other times it just omits part of the string.

When i tried using string literals instead of using input from the command line, everything worked fine. So i assume that there is an issue with the input part of the program specifiaclly.

This piece of the code resides in the main method

```
        while(true){
        System.out.print("$");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        s.useDelimiter("\n");
        String in = s.next();
        String out = "";

        if (in.startsWith("ks")) {
            out = ScrambleString.keepSpaces(in.substring(3));
        } else if (in.startsWith("fr")) {
            out = ScrambleString.fullRandom(in.substring(3));
        } else if (in.startsWith("kw")) {
            out = ScrambleString.randomByWords(in.substring(3));
        } else if (in.equals("exit")) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Syntax: [fr:ks:kw] sentence\n fr full random \n ks keep spaces \n kw keep words");
        }

        System.out.println(">>" + out); 
        }
```

These are the static functions called from above

```
/**
 * only ignore spaces while randomizing
 *
 * @param a
 * @return
 */
public static String keepSpaces(String a) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();

    char[] s = a.toCharArray();

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        char t = s[i];
        int num = r.nextInt(s.length);

        if (s[i] != ' ' && s[num] != ' ') {
            s[i] = s[num];
            s[num] = t;
        }

    }
    return String.valueOf(s);
}

/**
 * randomize every char regardless of word or space
 *
 * @param a
 * @return
 */
public static String fullRandom(String a) {

    a = a.toLowerCase();

    char[] s = a.toCharArray();

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        char t = s[i];
        int num = r.nextInt(s.length);

        s[i] = s[num];
        s[num] = t;

    }
    return String.valueOf(s);
}

/**
 * change the order of the characters per word. words are separated by spaces
 *
 * @param a
 * @return
 */
public static String randomByWords(String a) {
    String[] words = a.split(" ");
    String out = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        out += fullRandom(words[i]) + " ";
    }

    return out;
}
```

Here is a test run in cmd: [image: TestRunCMD]

And here is a test run using netbeans: 
[image: testRunNetbeans]

Comment: **Windows end-of-line is CR LF** but you've told `Scanner` to remove only the LF leaving CR as the last character of the line and thus a character _in_ the last word on the line `y o u CR` which is 'scrambled' to `o CR u y` plus space `" "`. Using `Scanner.hasNextLine,nextLine` (or `BufferedReader.readLine` with `!=null`) handles the different EOL conventions for you.

Comment: Thanks that worked... if you post your comment as an answer i will accept it.